# How do I use a function to manipulate an instance of an object's data in ruby?

Tags: ruby, function, object

I've been all over google and stack over flow and I can't seem to find the answer.

I need the "bookman" function to find the instance of 'cash' so that it can call cash's methods.

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Here is my code

```
class Account
  def initialize (deb_bal, cred_bal)
    @deb_bal = deb_bal
    @cred_bal = cred_bal
  end

  def debit(x)
    @deb_bal += x
  end

  def credit(x)
   @cred_bal += x
  end

  def balance
    bal = @deb_bal.to_i - @cred_bal.to_i
    if  bal < 0
      puts "Credit Balance of #{bal.abs}"
    else
      puts "Debit Balance of #{bal.abs}"
    end
  end
end

def bookman 

end

cash = Account.new(0,0)
#acts_rec = Account.new

cash.credit 100
bookman
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the object into the method:

```
...
def bookman(acct)
  acct.debit(50)
end

cash = Account.new(0, 0)
cash.credit 100
bookman(cash)
cash.balance

=> Credit Balance of 50
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either pass `cash` as an argument to the `bookman` function, or make `cash` an instance variable.